# Traversing List of Integers and ending on the last index which should be 0

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a method that checks if a List is solvable. Solvable in this context means 2 things:

1. The last index of the list is a 0.
2. Starting from the first index, each value indicates how many position you should go back or forth in the List. After walking the indexes you should end at the last index.

```
public class ListSolver {

  public boolean isSolvable(List<Integer> list) {
    if (list == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("List is null");
    }

    int listSize = list.size();
    int lastIndex = listSize - 1;
    int currentIndexValue;
    for (int i = 0, loopCounter = 0; i < listSize; i = i + currentIndexValue, loopCounter++) {
      try {
        currentIndexValue = list.get(i);
      } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return false;
      }

      // if traversed to last index and last index is 0
      if (i == lastIndex && currentIndexValue == 0) {
        return true;
      }

      // if infinite loop
      if (loopCounter > listSize) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

}
```

```
public class ListSolverTest {

  private ListSolver listSolver = new ListSolver();

  @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public void isSolvableGivenNullExpectIllegalArgumentException() {
    listSolver.isSolvable(null);
  }

  @Test
  public void isSolvableGivenListContainingZeroAndZeroExpectFalse() {
    boolean isSolvable = listSolver.isSolvable(Arrays.asList(0, 0));

    assertFalse(isSolvable);
  }

  @Test
  public void isSolvableGivenListContainingOneAndNegOneExpectFalse() {
    boolean isSolvable = listSolver.isSolvable(Arrays.asList(1, -1));

    assertFalse(isSolvable);
  }

  @Test
  public void isSolvableGivenListContainingZeroExpectTrue() {
    boolean isSolvable = listSolver.isSolvable(Collections.singletonList(0));

    assertTrue(isSolvable);
  }

  @Test
  public void isSolvableGivenListContainingOneAndZeroExpectTrue() {
    boolean isSolvable = listSolver.isSolvable(Arrays.asList(1, 0));

    assertTrue(isSolvable);
  }

  @Test
  public void isSolvableGivenListContainingNegOneExpectFalse() {
    boolean isSolvable = listSolver.isSolvable(Collections.singletonList(-1));

    assertFalse(isSolvable);
  }

}
```

The method was written using TDD, but I'm stuck now.

> How  can I refactor and make it more readable without creating new methods that feel contrived?

Comment: Do you personally feel that there's anything wrong with the current readability of the code?

Comment: Yes, I think that 3 if statement and a weird for loop in a single method is not good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function relies on no object state, so I would make it `static`.

You don't need both `listSize` and `lastIndex`.  To reduce clutter, I would keep just `lastIndex`.

`currentIndexValue` is too cumbersome a name, in my opinion.  "Current" is superfluous, especially when there is no "previous" or "next" involved.  "Index" just adds confusion.  So, I'd simply call it `value`.

The `for` loop is trying to do too much.  Considering that `currentIndexValue` is defined elsewhere, you can't understand how the loop behaves just by looking at the loop header.  So, I would just make it count iterations.

If `currentIndexValue` is 0, but `i` is not `lastIndex`, then `i` is never going to move.  You might as well return `false` immediately in that case.

It would be better to avoid triggering `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when `i` is negative.

```
public static boolean isSolvable(List<Integer> list) {
    if (list == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("List is null");
    }

    int lastIndex = list.size() - 1;
    int i = 0;
    for (int loopCounter = 1; loopCounter <= lastIndex; loopCounter++) {
        if (i < 0 || i > lastIndex) {
            return false;
        }
        int value = list.get(i);
        if (value == 0) {
            return i == lastIndex;
        }
        i += value;
    }

    return false;    
}
```

Comment: *"This function relies on no object state, so I would make it static."* **This is a bad advice!** `static` access makes *code depending on it* hard to change and hard to reuse. Therefore *no state change* is not a valid reason to make a method  `static`.

Comment: No, it is not. This is a simple utility method that should neither be mocked in unit tests nor extended or modified by anyone. Therefore making it `static` is good advice.

Comment: The correct answer would be to say it depends. This might be a core component, and I might also need an IrregularListSolver etc. Or no?

Comment: Why shouldn't I trigger an IndexOutOfBoundsException? Because it is more verbose?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you created your test in the order you mentioned here they have wrong order.

You should start with the most simple positive case.

> Disclaimer: the following code has been written in this form entirely an may not be correct.

I would suggest to start with this test:

```
  @Test
  public void listContainingSingleZeroIsSolvable() {
      boolean isSolvable = listSolver.isSolvable(Arrays.asList(0));

      assertTrue(isSolvable);
  }
```

This would result in the most simple solution:

```
public class ListSolver {
  public boolean isSolvable(List<Integer> list) {
     return true;
  }
}
```

---

Next I'd test the next simple to implement (implicit) rule:

```
  @Test
  public void zeroSomewhereElseThenAtLastIndexIsNotSolvable() {
      boolean isSolvable = listSolver.isSolvable(Arrays.asList(0,0));

      assertFalse(isSolvable);
  }
```

You have different way to implement that. But I'd chose an implementation that is oriented at the tests name. Terefore I'd compare the index of the first occurrence with the last index:

```
public class ListSolver {
  public boolean isSolvable(List<Integer> list) {
     return list.indexOf(0)<list.size()-1;
  }
}
```

---

Now we have to find the next easy to implement rule. That could be all `1`s:

```
  @Test
  public void consecutiveOnesWithTerminatingZeroAreSolvable() {
      boolean isSolvable = listSolver.isSolvable(Arrays.asList(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0));

      assertTrue(isSolvable);
  }
```

Magically we don't have to change anything because this test passes already.

---

What is another possibly failing test? An index pointing out of the array:

```
  @Test
  public void negativeValueLessThanOwnIndexIsNotSolvable() {
      // this name is not correct in mathematical sense but good enough I guess...
      boolean isSolvable = listSolver.isSolvable(Arrays.asList(1,1,1,-4,1,1,1,0));
      assertFalse(isSolvable);
  }
```

We need to add the loop to make that test pass:

```
public class ListSolver {
  public boolean isSolvable(List<Integer> list) {
     boolean hasZeroBeforeLastIndex= list.indexOf(0)<list.size()-1;
     if(hasZeroBeforeLastIndex) return false;
     for(int i =0; i<list.size();i++) 
        if(-i>list.get(i)) return false;
     return true;
  }
}
```

---

The other direction should fail too:

```
  @Test
  public void positiveValueBiggerThanSizeMinusOwnIndexIsNotSolvable() {
      boolean isSolvable = listSolver.isSolvable(Arrays.asList(1,1,1,1,8,1,1,0));
      assertFalse(isSolvable);
  }
```

lets add a second if as least possible change:

```
public class ListSolver {
  public boolean isSolvable(List<Integer> list) {
     boolean hasZeroBeforeLastIndex= list.indexOf(0)<list.size()-1;
     if(hasZeroBeforeLastIndex) return false;
     for(int i =0; i<list.size();i++) {
        if(-i>list.get(i)) return false;
        if(list.size()>= i+list.get(i)) return false;
     }
     return true;
  }
}
```

---

Now we have a "save" list and we can drill deeper into the loop:

```
  @Test
  public void lastIndexMustBeReachedBySizeMinusOneSteps() {
      boolean isSolvable = listSolver.isSolvable(Arrays.asList(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0));
      assertTrue(isSolvable);
  }
```

here we have to implement the actual stepping algorithm which wasn't needed until now:

```
public class ListSolver {
  public boolean isSolvable(List<Integer> list) {
     boolean hasZeroBeforeLastIndex= list.indexOf(0)<list.size()-1;
     if(hasZeroBeforeLastIndex) return false;
     int nextIndex = list.get(0);
     for(int i =0; i<list.size();i++) {
        if(-nextIndex>list.get(nextIndex)) return false;
        if(list.size()>= nextIndex+list.get(nextIndex)) return false;
        nextIndex+=list.get(nextIndex);
     }
     return list.size()==nextIndex;
  }
}
```

---

How do we handle skipped indexes? Should a skipped index be "solvable" or not? 
I say *yes* because this requires another change in the production code (saying *no* is already done):

```
  @Test
  public void skipOfAnIndexIsAllowed() {
      boolean isSolvable = listSolver.isSolvable(Arrays.asList(1,1,3,SKIPPED_VALUE,1,1,1,0));
      assertTrue(isSolvable);
  }
```

this is the solution so far:

```
public class ListSolver {
  public boolean isSolvable(List<Integer> list) {
     boolean hasZeroBeforeLastIndex= list.indexOf(0)<list.size()-1;
     if(hasZeroBeforeLastIndex) return false;
     int nextIndex = list.get(0);
     for(int i =0; i<list.size();i++) {
        if(0==list.get(nextIndex) return true;
        if(-nextIndex>list.get(nextIndex)) return false;
        if(list.size()>= nextIndex+list.get(nextIndex)) return false;
        nextIndex+=list.get(nextIndex);
     }
     return list.size()==nextIndex;
  }
}
```

---

The Point I'd like to make:

When writing the next test: don't look so much on your code you have so far, focus on the next most simple explicit or implicit *requirement* that may fail...

---

---

> I feel reluctant to use your test naming strategy. It is much harder to think of good names and to update when you refactor your methods. – Yoshua Nahar

1. Finding good names is the hardest part in programming, so always take your time to think about the names of your identifiers. I'm coding Java for 15+ years now and still it's hard to find good names to me too.
2. During refactoring you should **never** change your tests *manually*, neither names nor content. The tests are your *safety net* during refactoring that detect accidental changes of the already implemented behavior. But this net is only safe f it is unchanged during the critical phase!

   During refactoring you tests may be changed **only** by your IDEs *automated refactorings* (*rename in workspace*, *change method signature* or alike.

   That's why I get my test names from the *requirements* rather than from the implementation I have in mind. And that's why I did not include the tested method's name in my test names. The IDEs automated refactoring will not include the test names when the name of the tested method needs to be changed. And If you don't go and change the tests names *immediately* You'll never do it and they will lie for the rest of their life time.

> for example `zeroSomewhereElseThenAtLastIndexIsNotSolvable` is [...] misleading. Because 2, 0, 0 also passes. – Yoshua Nahar

This sample qualifies as solvable with *my* implementation?
<sub>As claimed I did not execute anything but I really doubt it.</sub>

> `zeroSomewhereElseThenAtLastIndexIsNotSolvable` is a terrible name, because [...] 2, 0, 0 also passes. – Yoshua Naha

This name is *perfect*!
This name expresses **my, the developers understanding** of the requirement by which this sample should qualify as "solvable". And *You, the reviewer* were able to point out my misunderstanding!

Without this test having that "misleading" name, when would you have recognized my error? 
Do you see the importance of that?

> You also have a couple of grammatical errors in your names. – Yoshua Nahar

Sorry, but I'm not a native speaker and it was late in the evening at my place. You're welcome to edit my post in order to fix the grammar if it stands in the way of understanding my approach.

Comment: I feel reluctant to use your test naming strategy. It is much harder to think of good names and to update when you refactor your methods.  And to take your tests for example `zeroSomewhereElseThenAtLastIndexIsNotSolvable` is a terrible name, because it's misleading. Because 2, 0, 0 also passes. You also have a couple of grammatical errors in your names.

Comment: But the point you make is correct imo. A unit test is rudimentary code documentation of business requirements.

Comment: @YoshuaNahar updated the answer.